# Laravel WRONG_STMT_PREPARE response size

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

I have two websites on the same shared hosting called ecommercetorricelli and progettost under the same username.

When I try to login ecommercetorricelli, after changing the DB settings in config/database.php file getting following error:

> **"QueryException in Connection.php line 647:** Wrong COM_STMT_PREPARE
>   response size. Received 7 (SQL: select * from utenti where email =
>   test@test.com limit 1)"

After checking the other website progettost, it also gives same error even though I didn't make any changes.

Comment: have you clear cache?

Comment: and also update composer as well once after clearing cache

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by changing PDO driver setting in

> config/database.php

try this.

```
    'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
/*****
rest of the constrain remain same
****/
    'options'   => [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,]
],
```